# Delphi 10 Android Broadcastreceiver for Headset Plugin does not work. What do I wrong?

Tags: android, delphi

I use Delphi 10 to create a mediaplayer app for my android phone. I use the following component to include a broadcastreceiver to my app:
https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component

This works perfect if I request a message for phone incoming calls (like in the demo app) and I use: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE

However, if I add a request for the headset plugin message:
android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
my app does not receive a message.

Any idea what I might do wrong?

Comment: Do you mean Delphi 10.0 Seattle, or Delphi 10.1 Berlin?  Is your app manifested to receive `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` intents in the first place?

Comment: In Berlin (not sure about Seattle), you can receive an Android `Intent` via  [`IFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler) and [`TMessageManager.SubscribeToMessage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageManager.SubscribeToMessage) for [`TMessageReceivedNotification`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/List_of_FireMonkey_Message_Types#FMX.Platform.TMessageReceivedNotification.Android) messages.

Comment: See Embarcadero's [AndroidIntents](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Berlin/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/AndroidIntents/) examples.

Comment: I work with Seattle. Seems like this solution is not yet available, here. But the component given above meanwhile works as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Intent action name is

```
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
```

Not

```
android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
```

This is documented in the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) documentation for [`ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG):

> ```
> public static final String  ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
> ```
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Broadcast Action: Wired Headset plugged in or unplugged. Same as [ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG), to be consulted for value and documentation.
>
> If the minimum SDK version of your application is [LOLLIPOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#LOLLIPOP), it is recommended to refer to the `AudioManager` constant in your receiver registration code instead.
>
> **Constant Value:   "android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"**

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you point me to a list where I can find the Intent action names? I havn't found any in the documentation and it would be helpful to avoid that kind of errors...